# get_dump() leaf value and AUC

Tags: machine-learning, decision-trees, xgboost

I have used Xgboost fitted a model with AUC around 0.73 and I printed out my last booster:

```
booster[599]:
0:[userkn_hometypecnt<22] yes=1,no=2,missing=1
    1:[userkn_60d_opencardniu_days<40] yes=3,no=4,missing=3
        3:[userkn_30d_opencardniu_days<13] yes=7,no=8,missing=7
            7:[userkn_60d_opencardniu_days<24] yes=15,no=16,missing=15
                15:[userkn_timeminperiod_firstday<1029] yes=29,no=30,missing=29
                    29:leaf=0.000352735
                    30:leaf=-0.0100666
                16:[userkn_rate_aopencardniusum_actiondaycnt<0.972506] yes=31,no=32,missing=31
                    31:leaf=0.000398097
                    32:leaf=-0.0129448
            8:[userkn_hometyperate<0.0977183] yes=17,no=18,missing=17
                17:leaf=0.0239075
                18:[userkn_rate_aopencardniusum_actiondaycnt<0.957994] yes=35,no=36,missing=35
                    35:leaf=-0.00201536
                    36:leaf=0.00858442
        4:[userkn_newacitoncntactiondayavg<8.82511] yes=9,no=10,missing=9
            9:[userkn_mingap_importcard_open<297306] yes=19,no=20,missing=19
                19:[userkn_rate_aopencardniusum_actiondaycnt<0.974763] yes=37,no=38,missing=37
                    37:leaf=-0.0138254
                    38:leaf=0.00521038
                20:[userkn_onlinetime_firstday<1961.5] yes=39,no=40,missing=39
                    39:leaf=0.0247849
                    40:leaf=-0.00297016
            10:[userkn_60d_opencardniu_days<59] yes=21,no=22,missing=21
                21:[userkn_rate_repeatcntmaxactionrepeatcnt_actioncnt<0.124787] yes=41,no=42,missing=41
                    41:leaf=0.0101992
                    42:leaf=-0.0222082
                22:leaf=0.0145614
    2:[userkn_hometyperate_firstday<0.25266] yes=5,no=6,missing=5
        5:[userkn_aenterapplyloanpagecntactiondayavg<0.787338] yes=11,no=12,missing=11
            11:[userkn_newacitoncntactiondayavg<8.48678] yes=23,no=24,missing=23
                23:[userkn_worktimeactionrate<0.36514] yes=43,no=44,missing=43
                    43:leaf=-0.0178327
                    44:leaf=0.0168168
                24:leaf=0.0254048
            12:[userkn_newacitontyperate_firstday<0.794737] yes=25,no=26,missing=25
                25:[userkn_newacitoncntactiondayavg<7.14581] yes=47,no=48,missing=47
                    47:leaf=0.0175715
                    48:leaf=-0.00748876
                26:leaf=0.0174804
        6:[userkn_aopencardniurate_firstday<0.0458042] yes=13,no=14,missing=13
            13:[userkn_avgperday_opencardniu_cnt<7.44167] yes=27,no=28,missing=27
                27:leaf=0.00171541
                28:leaf=-0.0229204
            14:leaf=0.00968641
```

If I am right, the leaf value is the value of logodds and it can be changed into a probability with the `sigmoid` function. However in the last booster all the leaf values changed to around 0.5 probability.

Which means all the samples will be marked as good/bad cases half and half? So it's no difference with a random guess at a binary classification?

Am I right or any other opinions are quite appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Could you clarify what you mean by *"However in the last booster all the leaf values changed to around 0.5 probability"?*

My understanding is when computing predicted probabilities, you'd need to add base score (default = 0.5) to estimated weight parameter (leaf score), like so:

$\hat{p} = \frac{\text{exp(0.5 + w)}}{\text{1 + exp(0.5 + w)}}$

where $\text{w}$ is the estimated leaf score.

Below, is the link to the default xgboost parameters in python API: https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html

```
class xgboost.XGBClassifier(max_depth=3, 
      learning_rate=0.1, n_estimators=100, silent=True, 
      objective='binary:logistic', 
      booster='gbtree', n_jobs=1, nthread=None, gamma=0, min_child_weight=1, 
      max_delta_step=0, subsample=1, colsample_bytree=1, 
      colsample_bylevel=1, 
      reg_alpha=0, reg_lambda=1, scale_pos_weight=1, base_score=0.5, 
      random_state=0, 
      seed=None, missing=None, **kwargs)
```

**base_score:**
The initial prediction score of all instances, global bias.

Does this answer your question?